# Is there a way to apply styles to all the certain elements/classes all over the page by using hover on one particular selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

Is there a way (only CSS, no JS) to apply styles to all the certain elements/classes all over the page (not only descendants or siblings, etc.) by using hover on one particular selector?

For example, here I want to block the `display:none;` of all the`<p>` tags in the page, regardless of their location in the site or descendants, siblings, etc., all the `<p>`.

[image]

Comment: You really only have the tilde selector but that doesn't answer your question. I know you said no JS, but I would dig deeper and ask why?… because that is really the only way this is going to happen.

Comment: Using the markup in your image (in the future please post code. See [mcve]) no, there isn't a way to do that without JavaScript since there's no way to select the previous sibling of your div

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the tilde. This only works if the elements you are trying to show are after the element you hover over though. Like this

```css
p {
  display: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.specialhover:hover~p,
.specialhover:hover~div p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="specialhover">Hover over me to show all hidden elements</div>
<p>Tada</p>
<div>Hover over me to show the p element
  <p>Tada2</p>
</div>
<p>Tada3</p>
```

Comment: Hovering over "Hover over me to show the p element" doesn't do anything

Comment: @j08691 - then add another CSS rule to target that one too. div:hover~p {display:block;}

Comment: That's fine, however your HTML structure differs from that of the OP. There's no way to select a parent or previous sibling with just CSS. Remove your `specialhover` div and let's see how hovering over the other div can change the `<p>` before it

Answer (score 0):

A button buried somewhere in the HTML is not going to be able to influence things back up the DOM using just CSS (as it's specified at the moment anyway).

The only thing I could think of is to have a checkbox which signals that you'd like to hover to show everything with an element following that is basically the ancestor of everything bar the body element.

TBH a less hacky way of doing it would be to use a bit of JS but as that's been ruled out here's a snippet using HTML and CSS:

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + .thelot:hover p{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>Click to enable the hovering</label><input type="checkbox"/>
<div class="thelot">
content of all sorts in here
<p>A paragraph</p>
More stuff
<p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```